# android - website not opening inside webview

Tags: android, eclipse

i am simply opening webpage inside of app by using webview, when i load the app its taking webpage out of app and opens in browser.

here is my code

xml

```
           <WebView
           android:id="@+id/webView1"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="162dp" />
```

java

```
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
    myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.domain.com/admin/");
```

please help me with it

thanks

Comment: Would be nice if you've posted the actual website address. Also your log cat if there are any warnings/errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

be sure to have  into your `AndroidManifest.xml` the permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

and try adding a `WebViewClient()`

```
myWebView .setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
```

Comment: yes it has internet permission... maybe external website that's why?

Comment: are you under a firewall? could i see the url?

Comment: yes i can see url and page...put it taking me out from app... and opens url in brower